# Suggestion for application distribution model

Tags: ipad, distribution, private

I am developing an iPad app that is designed to be released to private syndication clients. It is a replacement for an e-mail newsletter we produce and product management is exploring how to make the experience more dynamic and customizable for the end user. We are debating whether the app should be iOS native or a web app. Initially I was leaning towards native app but after some thought I realized Apple has no method that would allow us to distribute the app effectively anyway. An enterprise solution wouldn't work, as our end users would be from various outside companies. What we need is more of a private application that could only be downloaded with a pass code or log-in. I also considered having an app that is available  in the App store but requires you to log-in before any content is displayed, but I don't think Apple would approve and release an app with that type of functionality. At this point I am thinking a web app is the only way to go for us. Anyone have any experience with this type of issue or any comments/suggestions?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found you can submit apps that only certain people can access, so native app will work. Probably obvious to others, but I wasn't certain on it.

Comment: Where did you find that?  I have been looking for a solution for this for a while.

Comment: Dan, I misrepresented my answer. I found you can submit apps that require a password to access. In the app store anyone can download it, but the app would present a password screen and if you had no account you could not access any functionality. Sorry for the confusion.